# How to successfully connect Grafana to Apache IoTDB?

Tags: grafana, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am now trying to connect Grafana to Apache IoTDB, and I cannot successfully connect these two. The error message of Grafana is `Failed to connect to iotdb service. Get "http://127.0.01:18080/grafana/v1/login": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:18080: connect: connection refused`. What should I check to connect IoTDB to Grafana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Apache IoTDB Version 1.1? Check if the REST session service is enabled in IoTDB, and the firewall configuration allowed this service. Then you can change the `host` setting to a public IP.